# Force right-associativity when using left-associative C++ operator

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading, associativity

I'm trying to force right-associativity when using a left-associative C++ operator (like `operator+()`) but I'm "dying" just before the end (see the last `static_assert`).

Having some objects `A a; B b; C c; D d;`
and the overloaded `operator+()`, I would like to write `a+b+c+d` and  behind the scene to have `X<A, X<B, X<C,D>>>` (**X** being a custom binary op)

Does anybody have any hint? Or different approach?

Thanks in advance!

live example: https://godbolt.org/z/58dM6Ws4b

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <utility>

struct Tag{};//for class tagging
struct A: public Tag{};
struct B: public Tag{};
struct C: public Tag{};
struct D: public Tag{};

struct X0{};
template<typename L, typename R>
struct X: public X0{//binary op to force right-associativity
    using TL = L;
    using TR = std::conditional_t<std::is_base_of_v<Tag,L> && std::is_base_of_v<Tag,R>, R&, R>;
    L& l;
    TR r;
    X(L&l, R&r): l{l}, r{r}{}
    X(L&l, R&&r): l{l}, r{std::forward<TR>(r)}{}
    X(L&&l, R&r): X{l.l, X{l.r,r}} {}
};

template<std::derived_from<Tag> L, std::derived_from<Tag> R>
auto operator+(L& l, R& r){return X{l, r};} //for: a+b
template<std::derived_from<X0> L, std::derived_from<Tag> R>
auto operator+(L&& l, R&r){return X{l.l, X{l.r,r}};} //for: a+b+c

//================================================================
int main(){
    A a; B b; C c; D d;
    printf("-------- a+b\n");
    auto x2 = a+b;
    printf("-------- a+b+c\n");
    auto x3 = a+b+c; // <=> (a+b)+c
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(x3), X<A, X<B,C>>>);
    printf("-------- a+b+c+d\n");
    auto x4 = a+b+c+d; // <=> ((a+b)+c)+d
    //static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(x4), X<A, X<B, X<C,D>>>>); //<-- this fails
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Would it be possible for you to just write `d+c+b+a`? If the behaviour is commutative.

Comment: You still get left associativity for complex expressions (that last one calls `operator+<X<A, X<B, C> >, D>(X<A, X<B, C> >&&, D&)`). Why can't you just use a named function (`add`, with `auto x4 = add(a, add(b, add(c, d)));`) instead of trying to get an in-built operator to behave wrongly?

Comment: No, it is absolutely impossible to do right. `A+B+C` and `(A+B)+C` will always evaluate to the same thing whatever you do. For a right-associative operator they must be different.

Comment: Very simple to force right-associativity by just using parens:  `auto x4 = a+(b+(c+d));` and best of all it's self-documenting what you've done.

Comment: [Here](https://godbolt.org/z/ob9Kb795G) is a minimally modified approach that recursively calls the `operator+`. Pretty sure it's not a good path to go down though.

Comment: Thank you, @super! Please add your solution as an answer to get the credit. You deserve it! PS: having most people saying it is not possible... it is a good enough reason for me to try it! :)